# Erro ao salvar laravel 5.8

Tags: php, html, laravel

Eu possua duas tabelas relacionadas no momento de salvar tá acusando o seguinte erro SQL:

> "SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'id_data' doesn't have a default value (SQL: insert into `users` (`email_user`, `password_user`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (vfd, vgd, 2019-06-26 13:18:37, 2019-06-26 13:18:37))

Pensei que fosse um problema um problema de relacionamento, mas sem o relacionamento o erro persiste.

**Model Users**

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use App\Models\Data_users;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\App;

class Users extends Model
{
    protected $primaryKey = 'id'; 
    protected $fillable=[

                            'email_user',
                            'password_user',
                            'id_data'
                        ];

    public function userky(){
        return $this->belongsTo(Data_users::class);
    }
}
```

**Model Data_users**

```
use App\Models\Users;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Data_users extends Model
{

    protected $fillable= [
                            'name_user',
                            'mobile_phone_user',
                            'rg_user',
                            'cpf_user',
                            'nationalite_user', 
                            'creci',
                            'state_civil_user',
                            'profition_user'
                        ];



}
```

**Controller**

```
 public function save_user(Request $request)
    {

      $datacad=$request->all();

      $data_user=Data_users::create($datacad);
      $user=Users::create($datacad);



      $user->data_user()->associate($data_user);
      $user->save();





      //  dd($request->all());




    }
```

Comment: Sua tabela `users` possui a coluna `id_data`, que não possui valor *default* e você não está definindo um valor para ela na inserção.

Comment: Valeu Anderson Carlos Woss era isso mesmo.